# Why aren't the array values carrying over in switch cases?

Tags: java, arrays, global-variables

Why aren't the array values saving in my switch functions?
First I pressed 1, created my roster values. After I created the values, I press 2 it leads to ArrayOutOfBound error. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Please ignore the FileNotFoundExceptions. Need to work on that part after I fix what I'm doing wrong.

```
public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int numStudents;
public static String[] nameOfStudent;
public static int[] broncoID;
public static int[] grade;
```

^ These are my declared variables

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    startMenus(keyboard);
}

public static void startMenus(Scanner sc) throws FileNotFoundException {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("(Enter option # and press ENTER)\n");
        System.out.println("1. Create new Roster");
        System.out.println("2. Display Current Roster");

        int option = sc.nextInt();

        sc.nextLine();

        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            createRoster();
            break;
        case 2:
            displayRoster();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unrecognized Option!\n");
        }
    }
}

public static void createRoster() throws FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("Please list how many students there are.");

    numStudents = keyboard.nextInt();

    nameOfStudent = new String[numStudents];
    broncoID = new int[numStudents];
    grade = new int[numStudents];

    keyboard.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter full name of Student.");
        nameOfStudent[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Now please enter the BroncoID of Student.");
        broncoID[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Now please enter grade of Student (0-100)");
        grade[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Roster successfully created!");
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents ; i++){
        System.out.printf("Name: %9s\t Bronco ID: %5d \t Grade: %2d \n", nameOfStudent[i], broncoID[i], grade[i]);
    }
}

public static void displayRoster(){
    System.out.printf("Name: %9s\t Bronco ID: %5d \t Grade: %2d \n", nameOfStudent[1], broncoID[1], grade[1]);
```

}

The printf in the first case works, but it doesn't work in the second case. Error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Roster.displayRoster(Roster.java:115)
at Roster.startMenus(Roster.java:36)
at Roster.main(Roster.java:16)
```

Comment: On which line you are getting error?

Comment: why dont you have a `case 4` in your switch case?

Comment: In your code you add the record in nameOfStudent, broncoID and grade array at position 0, because array start from 0 position, while in displayRoster method you are retrieving from 1 position of array, so it's causing exception.

Answer (score 4):

An Array always starts with the index 0. You added one "Roster" to your Array. This Roster will get index 0. In your `displayRoster()` Method you want to show index 1, but your array only has index 0. So it will get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Instead of:

```
System.out.printf("Name: %9s\t Bronco ID: %5d \t Grade: %2d \n", nameOfStudent[1], broncoID[1], grade[1]);
```

Try:

```
System.out.printf("Name: %9s\t Bronco ID: %5d \t Grade: %2d \n", nameOfStudent[0], broncoID[0], grade[0]);
```

Comment: This must be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are using 2 cases in switch statement:

case 1 and 2

However, you're taking input as 1 for createroster and 4 for displayroster

either use "case 1" and "case 4" in switch statement.
or use:

```
System.out.println("1. Create new Roster");
System.out.println("2. Display Current Roster");
```

Comment: Err I forgot to fix that in the question, the case numbers are correct but the problem still exists

Comment: Error is coming in displayroster, can you share that code as well?

Comment: well.. in displayroster method: you are displaying nameOfStudent[1], broncoID[1], grade[1].... May be they are of size 1.. Try nameOfStudent[0], broncoID[0], grade[0].., If I'm not mistaken

Comment: Arrays start with 0 index not 1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Better modify the method displayRoster as :

   ```
   public static void displayRoster() {
       System.out.println("Enter the record number to be displayed[1 to numStudents :");
       int i = keyboard.nextInt();
       if(i <= nameOfStudent.length)
           System.out.printf("Name: %9s\t Bronco ID: %5d \t Grade: %2d \n", nameOfStudent[i-1], broncoID[i-1], grade[i-1]);
       else
           System.out.println("This is where you are trying to access element out of bound.");
   }
   ```
2. Input `option = 4` directs to the `default` switch case in your code which should S.out "`Unrecognized Option!"`